# Android iText text extraction

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, path-finding

Guys i'm having a problem making this run in android but no problems when i run it in java.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    am = this.getAssets();
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            try {
                parsePdf("android.resource://com.example.panalyzer_v1/raw/resume.pdf","android.resource://com.example.panalyzer_v1/raw/resume.txt");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
      }
    );
}

public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

This code will extract the whole text in the PDF and transfer it in a text file but I do not know if Android can do that.
I think my problem here is the filepathing: `parsePdf("assets/Resume.pdf","assets/Resume.txt");` I can't make it work.

I have changed the pathing but the error is not solved. I debugged it and i still got an error:

```
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.panalyzerdemo/com.example.panalyzerdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.example.panalyzerdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-22 20:16:13.850: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  ... 11 more
10-22 20:16:16.831: I/Process(657): Sending signal. PID: 657 SIG: 9
```

i know the problem and it is `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);`. Did i get the pathing wrong?

PS:I am a newbie when it comes to debugs. please correct me if its the wrong debug report.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To open an asset file in Android you should use `getAssets().open("Resume.txt")`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 solutions that you can try.

1. Instead of putting the file in assets folder put in a raw folder under res. And use the following path to refer it.
   "android.resource://[your_package_name]/raw/Resume.pdf"
2. Asset folder path should be given like this
   file:///android_asset/Resume.pdf
3. Instead of putting the file in assets folder put it in SD Card and SD card root path can be obtained like this
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will be trying 1 and 2, for 3 is it the same in a desktop accessing the file from a directory?

Comment: For 3, the function mentioned above will give you the path of root of the SD card. And then you need to append the relative path of your file depending upon where this is stored in SD Card. Sorry I could not understand the question of accessing from Desktop ?

Comment: btw, is this correct for 1 `parsePdf("android.resource://com.example.panalyzer_v1/raw/resume.pdf","android.resource://com.example.panalyzer_v1/raw/resume.txt");`?

Comment: yeah it seems correct if com.example.panalyzer_v1 is your application package name.

Comment: Thank you. The question i was talking about is what if the storage is internal like a desktop computer should i use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`?

Comment: @Dalving How will i know if the Pathing is Correct? its not showing any errors. Sorry if i'm asking too much question.

Comment: So what is happening now ? are you still not able to read the file ?

Comment: yes, im not able to read files yet. currently this line `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);` `pdf = "android.resource://com.example.panalyzer_v1/raw/resume.pdf"` is giving me an error and i do not know why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18405/discussion-between-christian-eric-paran-and-dalvin)

Answer (score 0):

ahh Yes! i solved it. instead of using file path i used:

`reader = new PdfReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resume));`

Comment: Great, another way of accessing resources :)